# Spring Boot & MongoTemplate: How to paginate a nested Object

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa

I'm struggling with what I think should be fairly basic but I honestly cant get my head around. I've seen a few similar topics here but none which satisfy my needs.

I have a basic Java Object which I persist to MongoDB using mongotemplate. This Pojo contains a LinkedHashSet of Strings which I would like to be able to paginated on as this list could be quite large.

Below is my pojo:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "BookCollection")
public class Collections {
    @Id
    private String _id;

    private String userId;

    @NotBlank(message = "Collection name is required")
    private String collectionName;

    private Boolean isPublic;

    private LinkedHashSet<String> bookIds = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    private AtomicInteger bookCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
}
```

Typically here is how I would paginated something from Mongo:

```
 @Override
    public Iterable<Books> findAllByUserId(String userId, Integer page, Integer size) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);

        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("userId").is(userId));
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("isDeleted").is(false));

        Long numOfDocumentCount = mongoTemplate.count(query, Book.class);

        query.with(pageable);
        query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdDate"));

        List<Book> bookList = mongoTemplate.find(query, Book.class);

        Page<Books> resultPage = PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(
                bookList,
                pageable,
                () -> numOfDocumentCount);
        return resultPage;
    }
```

Can someone please help me understand how I can achieve the same pagination on just the nested object in my Collection.class (bookIds). I've read about projects but to be honest its going over my head.

Many thanks

EDIT:

OK, so I've gotten what I think is close with this code:

```
    public Iterable<Collections> findOneByIdPagination(String collectionsId, Pageable pageable) {
        Query collectionsQuery = new Query();
        collectionsQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(collectionsId));

        ProjectionOperation collectionProjects = project().and("bookIds").slice(pageable.getPageSize(), pageable.getPageNumber()).as("bookIds")
                .and("bookIds").size().as("bookCount");

        TypedAggregation<Collections> agg = newAggregation(Collections.class,
                match(Criteria.where("_id").is(collectionsId)),
                collectionProjects);

        AggregationResults<Collections> aggregate = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Collections.class, Collections.class);

        AtomicInteger totalCount = aggregate.getMappedResults().get(0).getProjectCount();
        List<Collections> test = aggregate.getMappedResults();

        Page<Collections> resultPage = PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(
                test,
                pageable,
                totalCount::get);

        return resultPage;

    }
```

However there seems to be an issue with the details on the pagination response i.e. totalPages etc.

For instance, if I do a paginated request with values of page = 0 and size = 2

I get the following response:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "_id": "60c2048c8ed4c25bfafb531a",
            "userId": abcd123,
            "collectionName": "newbookcollection",
            "isPublic": null,
            "bookIds": [
                "asdadasd",
                "asdadsasdada"
            ],
            "bookCount": 4
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 2,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalElements": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "last": true,
    "size": 2,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 1,
    "empty": false
}
```

And here is the document in Mongo without any slicing:

```
{
            "_id": "60c2048c8ed4c25bfafb531a",
            "userId": abcd123,
            "collectionName": "newBookCollection",
            "isPublic": null,
            "bookIds": [
                "test1",
                "test2",
                "test3",
                "test4"
            ],
            "bookCount": 4
        }
```

As you can see the paginated response should not show last = true nor should it say totalPages = 1 or totalElements = 1

Comment: May I know what is the problem you face? If you dont need some fields, i=you can omit and get oly the contents, right?

Comment: Thanks for the response @varman, the problem I have is, I have a nested Array "bookIds" in my mongo Document. I want to be able to paginate on that array.

Comment: But u have dont all documents paginated, right? But u need the bookid to be paginated only, am i correct? So do u need the whole rppt documents?

Comment: Yes so I dont need the documents paginated. That I can do no problem. I only want the bookId array paginated. Thanks btw

Comment: Does this meet your expected output https://mongoplayground.net/p/yMxGFwvI3SQ